# How to Disable "Call Me" Button in Azure B2C TechnicalProfile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How can we disable "Call Me" Button and just leave "SMS me" button in the TechnicalProfile "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" in a custom policy?

```xml
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
          <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
            <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the authentication mode to SMS-only as follows:

```xml
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="setting.authenticationMode">sms</Item>
</Metadata>
```

You can also automatically send the authentication code as follows:

```xml
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="setting.autodial">true</Item>
</Metadata>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate.. where is all this documented just out of curiosity? Might check out some other settings as well like ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed etc

Comment: Many of [the technical profiles are documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles) but the phone factor one isn't documented as yet. I've created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25338) for this.

Comment: Can we do the same for Email Verification OTP - i.e. send code immediately when readonlyEmail is set (email address populated?)

Comment: @ChrisT Did you find a solution for the send code automatically for email?